Exploding dataframes in Julia
I have a Julia array like this:
Any[Any[["link_1", "link_2", "link_3"], "82", ["A B", "C D", "E F", "G H", "I J"]]]

I want to convert this into a data frame with three columns: link, value, and array. However, I want to "explode" the values inside ["link_1", "link_2", "link_3"] (similar to pandas.DataFrame.explode) and construct a dataframe in Julia. I could do so in Python using the explode function in Pandas, but how do I achieve the same in Julia?

Could you please provide an expected output as it is hard for me to understand what you want to achieve.

Julia has a specific package, Dataframes (link to documentation), that I would suggest looking at if you are dealing with dataframes. The function you are looking for is Dataframes.flatten()
# get the package
using Dataframes

# your data, in dataframe form
myRawData = DataFrame(
    :links=>[["link_1", "link_2", "link_3"]],
    :vals=>["82"],
    :array=>[["A B", "C D", "E F", "G H", "I J"]]
)

#= 
raw data, visualized:
1×3 DataFrame
 Row │ links                           vals    array
     │ Array…                          String  Array…
─────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ ["link_1", "link_2", "link_3"]  82      ["A B", "C D", "E F", "G H", "I …

=#

# flattening out the links col
flatten(myRawData,[:links])

#=
output, visualized:
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ links   vals    array
     │ String  String  Array…
─────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ link_1  82      ["A B", "C D", "E F", "G H", "I …
   2 │ link_2  82      ["A B", "C D", "E F", "G H", "I …
   3 │ link_3  82      ["A B", "C D", "E F", "G H", "I …
=#

This should replicate the functionality of Python's numpy.explode('links').
